# Local and Global variables (Java)

Tags: java, class

I have the class X and a variable called x
In my inner class Y I have a variable called y

I want: x = y

I made a Getter Method for Y and for X but the error accurs:
non-static method 'getY()' cannot be referenced from a static context.

I haven't set the getX() static nor final. I have tried it both ways as well but it's not working.

EDIT:

```
public class X {
    Variable v = new Variable();
    [... here is something done with v]

    class Y {
      Variable v_new = v;
      [works with v]

    }

    v = v_new; // ???
}
```

Comment: can you please show us some code?

Comment: " _... **non-static** method_ ". Just create an instance of class X by using the `new` keyword. Then you can access such non static methods.

Comment: you want x=y or X=Y???

Comment: Post code that compiles. You can't put code outside methods.

Comment: There are no `x`, `y`, `X`, or `Y` variables in the code shown. Names should follow the coding conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner class `Y` can access class `X`'s variable `v`, so no need to redeclare it as variable `v_new`...
If you must, then use a `public` getter method, and reference it through an instance of `Y`.

Something like this:

```
public class X {
  Variable v = new Variable();
  [... here is something done with v]

  class Y { 
    Variable v_new = v;
    [works with v]
    public Variable getV() { return v_new; }
  }

  Y y = new Y();
  v = y.getV();
}
```